# CodeMirror Markdown insert image URL

Tags: javascript, regex, image, markdown, codemirror

I am trying to insert image URLs to the right place in CodeMirror (markdown mode). When I type `![]()`, a block appears and allows me to upload an image and retrieve URL. I would put this URL into the `( )` of `![]()`, knowing that it should work regardless of the number of `![]()` in my text (each occurrence of `![]()` have its own block defined).

**You can see an example in Ghost CMS.**

I tried two things:

- Retrieve the position of each `![]()` listening to the keyup event and make a replaceRange -> does not work because the user can delete some text and change positions of occurrences
- Modify the DOM directly (do not change the text value in the instance of the editor)

Nothing is conclusive and I spent hours searching in the documentation if there was a method to obtain the range of each occurences of a regex (i.e getRanges(regex) -> array) in order to count the number of occurrences and change the good (found with images blocks indexes) with a replaceRange.

If anyone knows how to do ... Thanks!

**edit**

I resolved my problem with a regex replacement at the image block index :

```
var nth = 0;
txt = txt.replace(/\!\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)/g, function(match, alt, original) {
    nth++;
    // i = image block index
    return (nth === i+1) ? '![' + alt + '](' + href + ')' : match;
});

editor.setValue(txt);
```